# I have two tables emp and dept and I want to update the salary in emp table to increase by 10000 when the department name is "Software Engineer"

Tags: sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables emp and dept and I want to update the salary in emp table to increase by 10000 when the department name is "Software Engineer".emp table does not have dep name.

I have tried this query :

```
update emp 
set salary = salary + 10000 
where exists (select d.depatment_name, e.salary  
              from emp e  
              join department d on e.dep_id = d.department_id 
              where dep_name = 'Software Engineer');

select * from emp;
```

But its updating the salary for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the join is not working as expected. try selecting the department first then left joining employees. also, dept_name needed the "d." table alias.

```
update emp 
set salary = salary + 10000 
where exists (select d.depatment_name, e.salary  
              from department d
              left join emp e                
              on e.dep_id = d.department_id 
              where d.dep_name = 'Software Engineer');

select * from emp;
```